# Heimdall won't work on my RPi4b with OMV6 and Portainer

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi4, self-hosting, portainer, openmediavault

I have a Raspberry Pi 4b with Raspbian OS Lite 64bit.

On the RPi I have OMV6 as a NAS with a shared folder. I have Docker/Portainer installed via omv-extras.

Portainer works fine, but when I try to install Heimdall or any other self-hosted service, it won't work.

I've tried different types of portainer compose files like:

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  heimdall:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/heimdall:latest
    container_name: heimdall
    environment:
      - PUID=1001
      - PGID=100
      - TZ=Europe/Berlin
    volumes:
      - /srv/dev-disk-by-uuid-0ced8ae6-8f59-4918-8894-704b7b4363dc/docker-apps/docker/heimdall/config
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    restart: unless-stopped
```

Error:
`Error Code: failed to pull images of the stack: heimdall Pulling no matching manifest for linux/arm/v8 in the manifest list entries`

But when I tried to add the line `platform: linux/arm64` the stack will be successfully deployed, a container will be created, the container is "running" but the container still doesn't work and there is no heimdall installed on the defined ports.

There is also no IP-address or port shown:
[Screenshot Container Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OHXY.png)

This is the content of the logs if i try to see whats in the logs of the heimdall container:
[Screenshot Logs of Heimdall Container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4APA.png)

I've tried several different types of dashboards/other docker composed files of services but all with the same errors and problems.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: are you sure that port 80 and 443 are available on your host machine?

Comment: i've tried ports which aren't used and it still won't work - same problem..